# In SQL Server, what are the data types that we could not include in Insert statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an `insert` statement which will copy data from tables in one database to another database on the same server.

I need to generate the queries dynamically as I don't know the table names from the other database. I know that the column `TIMESTAMP` can not be included in the `INSERT` list as it will throw this error:

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

I need to know like this how many data types are there in SQL Server 2008. I can exclude these data types while inserting the data.

If anybody have any handy information it will be very helpful.

Comment: You cannot also insert into identity column unless identity_insert is set to on, but identity is not a datatype but a property, the data type for identity can be tinyint, smallint, int, bigint, decimal(p,0), or numeric(p,0)

Comment: I assume only TIMESTAMP has this limitation. Thanks for pointing out this as well:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

On my machine (SQL Server 2014) only `timestamp` is not allowed to be inserted into.

**Note:** there is also `rowversion`, which [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) lists as a synonym of `timestamp`, yet it does not appear in the `sys.types`.

Obviously there are other features they may prevent this from working (as mentioned in comments) e.g. `IDENTITY`

**Long answer**:

Here is how you can check for yourself:

Generate a create table script that has every supported type as a column:

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE #Types( ' + STUFF( 
( SELECT ', Type_' + name + ' ' + name
FROM sys.types
ORDER BY system_type_id
FOR XML PATH( '' )), 1, 1, '' ) + ' )'
```

You will get something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Types(  Type_image image, Type_text text, ..... )
```

Generate insert and select statements:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO #Types( ' + STUFF( 
( SELECT ', Type_' + name
FROM sys.types
ORDER BY system_type_id
FOR XML PATH( '' )), 1, 1, '' ) + ' )'

SELECT 'SELECT ' + STUFF( 
( SELECT ', CONVERT( ' + name + ', '''' )'
FROM sys.types
ORDER BY system_type_id
FOR XML PATH( '' )), 1, 1, '' )
```

**Note:** for `SELECT` we take advantage of the fact that for most types converting an empty string into a type will succeed e.g. '' -> convert( INT -> 0.

It will not work for all types, but they will be few, where you can then search for the type information on MSDN (e.g. [geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography)) to grab a sample value.

Once you have sorted out your default values and excluded types that SQL Server refuses to insert into you can can generate another table, say `#Types2` and insert values into it from `#Types` table.

Full code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Types(  Type_image image, Type_text text, Type_uniqueidentifier uniqueidentifier, Type_date date, Type_time time, Type_datetime2 datetime2, Type_datetimeoffset datetimeoffset, Type_tinyint tinyint, Type_smallint smallint, Type_int int, Type_smalldatetime smalldatetime, Type_real real, Type_money money, Type_datetime datetime, Type_float float, Type_sql_variant sql_variant, Type_ntext ntext, Type_bit bit, Type_decimal decimal, Type_numeric numeric, Type_smallmoney smallmoney, Type_bigint bigint, Type_varbinary varbinary, Type_varchar varchar, Type_binary binary, Type_char char, Type_timestamp timestamp, Type_nvarchar nvarchar, Type_sysname sysname, Type_nchar nchar, Type_hierarchyid hierarchyid, Type_geometry geometry, Type_geography geography, Type_xml xml )
INSERT INTO #Types(  Type_image, Type_text, Type_uniqueidentifier, Type_date, Type_time, Type_datetime2, Type_datetimeoffset, Type_tinyint, Type_smallint, Type_int, Type_smalldatetime, Type_real, Type_money, Type_datetime, Type_float, Type_sql_variant, Type_ntext, Type_bit, Type_decimal, Type_numeric, Type_smallmoney, Type_bigint, Type_varbinary, Type_varchar, Type_binary, Type_char, Type_nvarchar, Type_sysname, Type_nchar, Type_hierarchyid, Type_geometry, Type_geography, Type_xml )
SELECT  CONVERT( image, '' ), CONVERT( text, '' ), CONVERT( uniqueidentifier, '0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong' ), CONVERT( date, '' ), CONVERT( time, '' ), CONVERT( datetime2, '' ), CONVERT( datetimeoffset, '' ), CONVERT( tinyint, '' ), CONVERT( smallint, '' ), CONVERT( int, '' ), CONVERT( smalldatetime, '' ), CONVERT( real, '' ), CONVERT( money, '' ), CONVERT( datetime, '' ), CONVERT( float, '' ), CONVERT( sql_variant, '' ), CONVERT( ntext, '' ), CONVERT( bit, '' ), CONVERT( decimal, '0' ), CONVERT( numeric, '0' ), CONVERT( smallmoney, '' ), CONVERT( bigint, '' ), CONVERT( varbinary, '' ), CONVERT( varchar, '' ), CONVERT( binary, '' ), CONVERT( char, '' ), CONVERT( nvarchar, '' ), CONVERT( sysname, '' ), CONVERT( nchar, '' ), CONVERT( hierarchyid, '/1/3/' ), geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0 ), geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )', 4326), CONVERT( xml, '' )

CREATE TABLE #Types2(  Type_image image, Type_text text, Type_uniqueidentifier uniqueidentifier, Type_date date, Type_time time, Type_datetime2 datetime2, Type_datetimeoffset datetimeoffset, Type_tinyint tinyint, Type_smallint smallint, Type_int int, Type_smalldatetime smalldatetime, Type_real real, Type_money money, Type_datetime datetime, Type_float float, Type_sql_variant sql_variant, Type_ntext ntext, Type_bit bit, Type_decimal decimal, Type_numeric numeric, Type_smallmoney smallmoney, Type_bigint bigint, Type_varbinary varbinary, Type_varchar varchar, Type_binary binary, Type_char char, Type_nvarchar nvarchar, Type_sysname sysname, Type_nchar nchar, Type_hierarchyid hierarchyid, Type_geometry geometry, Type_geography geography, Type_xml xml )

INSERT INTO #Types2(  Type_image, Type_text, Type_uniqueidentifier, Type_date, Type_time, Type_datetime2, Type_datetimeoffset, Type_tinyint, Type_smallint, Type_int, Type_smalldatetime, Type_real, Type_money, Type_datetime, Type_float, Type_sql_variant, Type_ntext, Type_bit, Type_decimal, Type_numeric, Type_smallmoney, Type_bigint, Type_varbinary, Type_varchar, Type_binary, Type_char, Type_nvarchar, Type_sysname, Type_nchar, Type_hierarchyid, Type_geometry, Type_geography, Type_xml )
SELECT Type_image, Type_text, Type_uniqueidentifier, Type_date, Type_time, Type_datetime2, Type_datetimeoffset, Type_tinyint, Type_smallint, Type_int, Type_smalldatetime, Type_real, Type_money, Type_datetime, Type_float, Type_sql_variant, Type_ntext, Type_bit, Type_decimal, Type_numeric, Type_smallmoney, Type_bigint, Type_varbinary, Type_varchar, Type_binary, Type_char, Type_nvarchar, Type_sysname, Type_nchar, Type_hierarchyid, Type_geometry, Type_geography, Type_xml
FROM #Types
```